# Given a specific nullspace $N(A)$ how many matrices can we create from it?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let's say I have the following problem, as an example

> Construct a matrix whose nullspace consists of all combinations of $\langle 2,2,1,0 \rangle$, and $\langle3,1,0,1 \rangle$

Two possible matrices that satisfy this are

$$A_1 = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ A_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -2 & -3 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

But my question is there a way to generalize this result? Can we find an upper bound on the number of matrices $A$ that can be created from this specified nullspace $N(A)$?

Furthermore is there a theorem, or result that generalizes the number of matrices $A$ that we can create from  any *arbitrary* nullspace $N(A)$?

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: @Matthew Leingang, currently no, but I would be highly interested in learning about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a matrix $A$ with nullspace $N(A)$, and a non-zero scalar $\alpha$. What is the nullspace of $\alpha A$? If you can prove that it is also $N(A)$, then you have shown that there are infinitely many matrices with this nullspace, and hence no upper bound exists.